# Nodejs callbacks to methods or promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am new to Node and I saw a callback hell pattern appear in my application which makes it hard to read.

After some research the internet is giving 2 main solutions:

**-Export out the functions**

turn this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var myFile = '/tmp/test';  
fs.readFile(myFile, 'utf8', function(err, txt) {  
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    txt = txt + '\nAppended something!';
    fs.writeFile(myFile, txt, function(err) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('Appended text!');
    });
});
```

into this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function notifyUser(err) {  
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('Appended text!');
};

function appendText(err, txt) {  
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    txt = txt + '\nAppended something!';
    fs.writeFile(myFile, txt, notifyUser);
}

var myFile = '/tmp/test';  
fs.readFile(myFile, 'utf8', appendText);
```

and
**use Promises**

I am leaning more toward the exports of function but the Internet is saying that promises are the better alternative to handling async calls.

I do not want to get into something to later have to change my coding habits/style to match standard convention, its better to start on the right path.

So should I just start using promises or is the exporting of function is a fine solution?

Comment: How about "readFileSync" ?

Comment: @blackmiaool: Don't use synchronous functions in NodeJS without a really, really good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a third option now which may take this out of the realm of pure opinion: Promises + `async`/`await`:

ES2017 (the spec coming out in June) will feature `async`/`await`, which provide simpler syntax for consuming promises in simple use cases, and NodeJS already supports them in the current version of Node v7 (v7.7.2 as of this writing).

With promises and `async`/`await`, your code would look like this:

```
const p = require(/*...some theoretical promisifier...*/).promisifier;
const fs = require('fs');

async function go() {
    const myFile = '/home/tjc/temp/test';  
    let txt = await p(fs.readFile, myFile, 'utf8');
    txt = txt + '\nAppended something!';
    await p(fs.writeFile, myFile, txt);
    console.log('Appended text!');
}

go().catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

**It's still asynchronous,** it's just that the syntax for simple promise use cases is simpler, allowing you to have the code reflect the logic without intermediary `then` callback functions.

Notice that you can only use `await` from within an `async` function (since they manage promises behind the scenes). Also note that NodeJS is going to get uppity about unhandled promise rejections soon, hence making sure we do the `catch` on `go()`.

I believe the above converts roughly to the following:

```
const p = require(/*...some theoretical promisifier...*/).promisifier;
const fs = require('fs');

function go() {
    const myFile = '/home/tjc/temp/test';  
    return p(fs.readFile, myFile, 'utf8').then(txt => {
        txt = txt + '\nAppended something!';
        return p(fs.writeFile, myFile, txt).then(() => {
            console.log('Appended text!');
        });
    });
}

go().catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

...but of course if you were writing it yourself, you'd organize it differently:

```
const p = require(/*...some theoretical promisifier...*/).promisifier;
const fs = require('fs');

function go() {
    const myFile = '/home/tjc/temp/test';  
    return p(fs.readFile, myFile, 'utf8')
        .then(txt => {
            txt = txt + '\nAppended something!';
            return p(fs.writeFile, myFile, txt);
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Appended text!');
        });
}

go().catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

As you can see, in terms of clarity, `async`/`await` bring a lot to the table for simple use cases. (For more complex use cases, you still have to fall back to explicit promise handling.)

Whether that takes us out of the realm of opinion, though, is another question. And naturally, keeping your functions small and composable is a good thing, whether you're using promises or not.

---

About `p` in the above: There are various libs out there for promisifying APIs written using Node's standard callback mechanism; in the above I'm using a theoretical one. Here's a very, very, very simple implementation of `p` above:

```
const p = (f, ...args) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        args.push((err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
        f(...args);
    });
};
exports.promisifier = p;
```

...but you can find libs that take a more thorough approach.

Comment: In the example without `async`/`await` you should move `.then`  containing the `console.log('Appended text!');`  one level up. Otherwise it will have the same problem with nesting level as with _callback hell_.

Comment: @t.niese: Thanks. I didn't introduce that code block very well. I meant to say that the `async`/`await` effectively translates to that, not that that's how you'd *want* to do it with promises. I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

Promises are great because they give the code a more "synchronous" structure, i.e. returning data instead of providing asynchronous callback for continuation.

Lets say you want to write a function that reads into a file and extracts its data. With callback you would write:

```
function readMyFile(cb) {
    fs.readFile('/tmp/test', function (err, txt) {
        if (err || !txt) {
            return cb(null);
        }

        return cb(txt);
    });
}
```

which is fine but it promotes everything that you've mentioned (callback hell, lack of readiness, etc...)

Using promises, you would write:

```
function readMyFile() {
    return fs.readFileAsync('/tmp/test');
}
```

(Most APIs have an implementation that returns promises, if not, you can wrap callback APIs to make them return a promise)

When you use promises, your method actually return something (which is the reason why i said that promises give the code a more"synchronous" structure), what they return is not the actual result but a promise or an handle that wraps the result for future use.
This has a great benefit over callbacks because when you have a promise you can either wait for the result like you would have done with callbacks:

```
promise = readMyFile();
promise.then(function (data) {
    ...
});
```

You can do things that in the callback world would have resulted in callback hell, like doing something after the promise returns:

```
 promise.then(sendDataToServe)
       .then(storeServerReplyInDatabase);
```

Waiting for several promises at once:

```
Promise.all([promiseA, promiseB])
       .then(function (resA, resB) {
        ...
    });
```

Handling errors more elegantly (instead of passing an "err" argument everywhere):

```
Promise.all([promiseA, promiseB])
       .then(function (resA, resB) {
        ...
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

You can already see that using promises over callbacks promotes a much more elegant way to writing asynchronous code.

Promises can be used if you are using newer versions of javascript ES6, or by downloading modules like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) or [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer with a great insight and informations.